# PHP - include/require/insert some data from one file to another

Tags: php, include

I'm not really familiar with php and would like to ask you to help me.

I want to insert `css` styling data from `styles.css` file into the `<style>` tag inside of `index.php`, and not sure how to do so with secure and optimized way.

Should I use `<?php include 'styles.css;?>` or `<?php require 'styles.css;?>` or what exactly should I do in order to insert the data in the optimized and secure way, please?

Comment: Is there a reason why you wouldn't just use `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css>` instead of using PHP?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`require`/`include` is for parsing a PHP file, not copying content.

Just read the file and `echo` the contents.

```
<?= file_get_contents('styles.css') ?>
```

where `<?=` is a shorthand for `<?php echo`.

Note that the include path in PHP environment may be different from that in the HTML, as understood by the browser. Better use `__DIR__ . '/styles.css'` to prevent problems.

Comment: Why so pushy? I couldn't accept it at the time because of the system. Also, can't upvote it due to low reputation rrating

Comment: @markie the actual problem is that your comment is too chatty, which is not recommended.

Answer (score 1):

I use the *readfile()* for this. I think it does not load the whole file into the memory, so it is safer for outputting a large files. So the code can be:

```
<?php readfile('styles.css') ?>
```